# Is $-x^4 = (-x)(-x)(-x)(-x)$ or $-(x^4)$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

$$
x^4 - 3x^2 = 1 \le x^4 - 3x^4 + x^4\\
x^4 - 3x^2 = 1 \le -x^4\\
$$
Is $-x^4 = (-x)(-x)(-x)(-x)$ or  $-(x^4)$?

Comment: It's $-(x^4)$. It makes sense to define order of operations this way; if we wished to write $(-x)^4$, we would almost always write $x^4$.

Comment: Not all software uses the [order of operations conventions for unary minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Unary_minus_sign) correctly.

Comment: I'll take that into account, thank you.

Comment: Also, $a^{b^c}=a^\left(b^c\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(-x)^4=x^4$$
Whereas $$-x^4=-(x^4)$$
The appearance of () changes the answer

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification. It has always confused me.